# TXTEXTCONTROL set language

Tags: txtextcontrol, uiculture

I've been testing out the TXTEXTCONTROL and I cna't find how to change ui culture or set language in the component with javascript.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's TXTEXTCONTROL ?

Comment: https://www.textcontrol.com/products/asp-dotnet/tx-text-control-dotnet-server/demos/

Comment: Have you been able to sort it out?

Comment: I manually translated every thing. Inside installation folder you van compile a XML file and place you translation.